# Dnsmasq forward refused to other Dnsmasq in Docker container

Tags: docker, linux-networking, subdomain, dnsmasq

Given two DNS servers, one runs on localhost (127.0.0.1:53) and the other in a Docker container (172.18.0.3:5300).

When I tried to check domain resolve **through at localhost DNS** with `dig` or `nslookup` commands the **request is refused**:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ nslookup whoami.docker
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find whoami.docker: REFUSED
```

and checked with `dig` but the result is similar:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ dig A whoami.docker

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> A whoami.docker
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 10447
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;whoami.docker.         IN  A

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 26 18:59:31 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

then the following log entries created:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ tail -F /var/log/syslog:
[...]
Mar 26 18:45:27 adam-desktop dnsmasq[10105]: query[A] whoami.docker from 127.0.0.1
Mar 26 18:45:27 adam-desktop dnsmasq[10105]: forwarded whoami.docker to 172.18.0.3
Mar 26 18:45:32 adam-desktop dnsmasq[10105]: query[A] whoami.docker from 127.0.0.1
Mar 26 18:45:32 adam-desktop dnsmasq[10105]: config error is REFUSED
```

But when I specified the 2nd DNS server in the command, the response is the expected:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ dig A @172.18.0.3 -p 5300 whoami.docker

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> A @172.18.0.3 -p 5300 whoami.docker
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5930
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;whoami.docker.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
whoami.docker.      0   IN  A   172.18.0.4

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 172.18.0.3#5300(172.18.0.3) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 26 18:58:08 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

So I don't understand why not working the resolving chain:

Request(whoami.docker) ->DNS1(127.0.0.1:53) -> DNS2(172.18.0.3): found entry(172.18.0.4 - whoami.docker) -> and return to client.

The localhost DNS configuration (**dnsmasq.conf**):

```
port=53
domain-needed
bogus-priv
strict-order
no-resolv

# Private DNS server on Docker network
server=/docker/172.18.0.3

#Use the Google nameservers
server=8.8.8.8
server=1.1.1.1

rebind-domain-ok=/.docker/

user=dnsmasq
#group=dnsmasq

listen-address=172.18.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 127.0.0.1

bind-interfaces
cache-size=0
log-queries
```

The NetworkManager config(**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**):

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[...]
```

The 2nd DNS server config (inside a Docker container - IP address: **172.18.0.3**):

```
port=5300
domain-needed
bogus-priv
log-queries
no-resolv
no-hosts

strict-order

#Use the Google nameservers
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

#serve all company queries using a specific nameserver
domain=docker

#explicitly define host-ip mappings
# Testing container
address=/whoami.docker/172.18.0.4
```

Content of **/etc/resolv.conf**:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search home
options edns0 trust-ad
```

The Docker-Compose file which defines the **DNS** and the **whoami** containers:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  dnsmasq:
    image: jpillora/dnsmasq
    container_name: dnsmasq
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        - ./dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf:ro
        - ./dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d:rw
    networks:
      devnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5300:53/udp"
      - "0.0.0.0:5300:53/tcp"
      - "0.0.0.0:5380:8080"
    environment:
      - HTTP_USER=foo
      - HTTP_PASS=bar
      # - VIRTUAL_HOST=ns.dev.home

  whoami:
      image: jwilder/whoami
      container_name: whoami
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "0.0.0.0:8000:8000"
      environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.docker
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      networks:
        devnet:
          ipv4_address: 172.18.0.4

networks:
  devnet:
    driver: "bridge"
    external: true
    enable_ipv6: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with followed the next articles.

**1st step:** I use to NetworkManager built-in dnsmasq instead of standalone installation:
[DNSMasq + Network Manager + Docker = Fun?](https://nice.kiwi/2021/01/18/dnsmasq-network-manager.html)

**2nd step:** I modified Docker Compose file: dropped host port definition in port mappings:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  dnsmasq:
    image: jpillora/dnsmasq
    container_name: dnsmasq
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        - ./dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf:ro
        - ./dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d:rw
    networks:
      devnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    ports:
      - "53/udp"
      - "53/tcp"
      - "0.0.0.0:5380:8080"
    environment:
      - HTTP_USER=foo
      - HTTP_PASS=bar

  whoami:
      image: jwilder/whoami
      container_name: whoami
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "0.0.0.0:8000:8000"
      environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.dev.home
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      networks:
        devnet:
          ipv4_address: 172.18.0.4

networks:
  devnet:
    driver: "bridge"
    external: true
    enable_ipv6: false
```

**3rd step:** Modified dnsmasq config file on remote DNS server (on Docker network) and separated domain configs to standalone config files inspired by:
[Running dnsmasq in Docker](https://blog.csainty.com/2016/09/running-dnsmasq-in-docker.html)
**/etc/dnsmasq.conf:**

```
port=53
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-hosts
keep-in-foreground
bind-interfaces
no-resolv
expand-hosts
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# changed domain from .docker to .dev.home
domain=dev.home 

#log all dns queries
log-queries

conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d
```

**/etc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.d/1.whoami.conf:**

```
address=/whoami.dev.home/172.18.0.4
txt-record=txt.whoami.dev.home,txt-whoami.whoami.dev.home
```

**4th step:**
Add extra rules to UFW (**/etc/ufw/after.rules**) to allow Docker internal networking properly followed by [To Fix The Docker and UFW Security Flaw Without Disabling Iptables](https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker)